# Classical mechanics as a limit of quantum mechanics?

Tags: physics, fourier-transform, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Paul Dirac states in his book the principles of quantum mechanics that “*...classical mechanics may be regarded as the limiting case of quantum mechanics when h tends to zero.*”

Fine, but how to actually show that is the case? The following discussion is my own understanding of this problem and how to state it in mathematical terms.

We know that in quantum mechanics both the position and momentum become probability distributions, $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ and $|\phi(p,t)|^2$, that are connected by the (suitably scaled) Fourier transformation $\psi(x) = (\mathcal{F}\phi)(p)$, where $p=\hbar x$. Also, the Heisenberg's uncertainty relation illustrates the mutual limit for those distributions, i.e. $\Delta(\psi)\Delta(\phi) \geq \hbar/2$. But I haven't found an explanation that shows why those distributions are allowed to become classical-like delta-distributions as $\hbar \rightarrow 0$. Maybe there is some obvious scaling argument why making the $\hbar$ smaller allows to squeeze both distributions in the Heisenberg's uncertainty relation?

> **More precisely**: How to show (if possible?) that if $\hbar$ tends to zero, then the following functions $\psi, \phi \in L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$ can both be sharply localized?
> $$\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\phi(p,t)e^{ip \cdot x/\hbar}dp \, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\text{and}\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\phi(p,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\psi(x,t)e^{-ip \cdot x/\hbar}dx.$$

---

Of course, the transition $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ only allows to pass the uncertainty principle. After that we are free to prepare a quantum state of a mass particle with approximately delta-distributions for both the position and momentum. Then the averaged equation of motion, i.e. the Ehrenfest theorem $m\frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle=\langle p\rangle$, where $\langle x\rangle = \int x|\psi(x,t)|^2 dx$ and $\langle p\rangle = \int p|\phi(x,t)|^2 dp$, is approximately the desired, point-like classical equation of motion $m\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=p(t)$.

Comment: Use `\langle,\rangle` for braces: $\langle x,y\rangle$

Comment: This better fits in physics stack exchange.

Comment: And has been asked on that site: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61569/hbar-rightarrow-0-in-quantum-mechanics and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102082/does-limit-hbar-rightarrow-0-in-quantum-mechanics-mean-anything

Comment: @Peter I think this question is about some suitable property of Fourier transform.

Comment: @Joe Thanks but those answers are not close enough.

Comment: The point arises many more times in the PSE, and the answers to the dozen interlinked questions there cover the waterfront. Much of the confusion lies in failure to compare apples with apples, i.e. describing QM and its CM limits in a common language and ambit. When one does this, by studying QM in phase space, one sees that situations (dynamical equations, expectation values, entropies, etc...) involving characteristic actions S much larger than ℏ are functions of ℏ/S and so are corrected by negligible/infinitesimal terms. There is no non-analytic dependence on that ratio...

Comment: No such scaling argument! In fact, the Fourier transform dictates that the widths of the coordinate w.f. and the momentum w.f.  multiply to *equal*  ℏ/2, e.g. for Gaussians, the precursors to δ-functions, which of course, are not square integrable! Huge decohered systems, however, may occupy regions in phase space much larger than  ℏ, so that parameter becomes insignificant.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your answer. But what is your opinion, can we approach this question by studying directly when both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$ become arbitrary small? Apparently that Fourier connetion holds all the time and in every physical potential?

Comment: No, it is impossible to beat the uncertainty principle at that level. The classical limit works by decohering huge systems, for huge variances on the scale of hbar.

Comment: @CosmasZachos But if we consider a situation when $\hbar$ tends to zero?

Comment: It never tends to o. It is a number. Large actions make its ratio with them tend to zero. The UP never breaks down: it is overwhelmed….

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ok, thanks for your answers. I was just considering if very small $\hbar$ allows very small values for both $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$.

Answer (score 2):

The uncertainty principle is [part and parcel of Fourier analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) and cannot be evaded. In fact, nondimensionalization of ℏ by absorbing it into the units of *x* and *p* makes the  ℏ/2 on the right hand side of the inequality equal to 1!  It cannot go away. (In signal processing this amounts to the Gabor limit).

The only way to ignore it is to make it less significant, in macroscopic systems with a *huge* characteristic action *S*. In such systems, the decohered wavefunction still has
$$
\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt S} \frac{\Delta p}{\sqrt S} \geq \frac{\hbar}{S} ,
$$
so the widths of the *x* and *p* spreads (the variances) can still not go to zero, but, on that scale (of *S*) they can be very-very small and let the distributions *appear* sharply localized,  on the scale of *S*, a macroscopic lab action quantity, localized in units suitable for *S*. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/209664/66086), or [else](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/209482/66086).

That is to say, the distributions of *x* and *p* are not arbitrarily sharp on the scale of $\sqrt \hbar$, but they *can be* quite sharp on the scale of $\sqrt S$, and may be taken to be δ-functions in classical and classical statistical mechanics.

The deeper technical feature of this limit, whose subtleties are often swept under the rug, is that observable quantities of interest are analytic functions in $\hbar/S$, and so all orders $O(\hbar/S)$ may be dropped consistently in most expressions, as routine in deformation quantization, linked above.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts (+1). I'll try to digest it.